# Keyboard shortcuts for basic ops in Stage Manager

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, ventura, stage-manager

In stage manager, what are keyboard shortcuts for

1. Toggle between apps in the focused group?
2. Switch which group is in focus?

Command + backtick sort of works for #1, but not really.